# Get declared variable in single.php to work in comments.php without re-declaring it

Tags: comments

I have declared a variable in my single.php

```
$title  = 'myvar';
```

Can I get it in my comments.php without re-declaring it again?

I use this code to get the comments.php templage:

```
<? comments_template( '', true );  ?>
```

Ty

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the actual variable definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**`comments_template()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template) only accepts two parameters: `$file` (string) and `$separate_comments` (Boolean). So, it does not have a way to pass an arbitrary variable as a parameter.

The two methods I generally use are:

1. Globalize the variable
2. Wrap the variable inside a function that returns the data you want, and then call it wherever you need it.

Answer (score -3):

You can use php session variables to utilize the myvar variable anywhere you want.

```
if(!$_SESSION['myvar']){

    $_SESSION['myvar'] = 'myvar';

}

echo $_SESSION['myvar'];
```